# Access memory via a flat file in Linux

Tags: linux, memory

I understand everything is a flat file in Linux. How hard is it to dump the contents of the main memory into a flat file? Does it already exist in Linux? If yes, what's the path to the file? What are the default permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/dev/mem` is [probably what you are looking for](http://lwn.net/Articles/147901/), this file is manipulated like any other device file with `dd` and other utilities.

Permissions on my Debian linux system are:

`crw-r-----  1 root kmem      1,   1 Aug 21 09:31 mem`

Answer (score 0):

kcore is (should be) an exact copy of what is running in memory.

```
cat /proc/kcore
```

should be readable by everyone.

Comment: On my system it's `-r-------- 1 root root`

Comment: It had better not be readable by anyone but root, since it allows snooping on the memory of every process. `/proc/kcore` on Linux is readable only by root. Also, `/proc/kcore` is the kernel's memory mapping; [`/dev/mem` is the physical RAM](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20525/access-memory-via-a-flat-file-in-linux/20526#20526).